# How to find the N most common occurring element in a list?

Tags: python, graph

I have a large list of tuples like `[('a','b'), ('a','c'), ('b','e'), ('a','d')]` and I would like to find top N popular entries in this list. The most popular is the one which is repeated the most. Here top two popular are `a` and `b`. How can I utlize `networkx` to solve this problem if the number of list items are of million size?

```
import networkx as nx
lists = [('a','b'), ('a','c'), ('b','e'), ('a','d')]
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(pair_names)
nx.degree(G)
```

this gives me list of popularity but I am having trouble displaying the top N popular items.

Comment: ***I would like to find top N popular entries in this list.*** Please provide some example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any particular reason why you would want to use `networkx`?

You can achieve this simply with `collections.Counter` and `itertools.chain`:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

l = [('a','b'), ('a','c'), ('b','e'), ('a','d')]

Counter(chain.from_iterable(l)).most_common(2)
```

*NB. Here for the top 2*

Output: `[('a', 3), ('b', 2)]`

To only get the keys in decreasing order of frequency:

```
c = Counter(chain.from_iterable(l))

list(dict(c.most_common(2)))
```

Output: `['a', 'b']`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a for loop to iterate over the degrees.

```
import networkx as nx
lists = [('a','b'), ('a','c'), ('b','e'), ('a','d')]
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(lists)
N = 2
dvweight = nx.degree(G)
popular_nodes = [nodes[0] for nodes in dvweight]
print(popular_nodes[:N])
```

OUTPUT

```
['a', 'b']
```